# ¿Cómo descargar el contenido de una variable JSON en mi php?

Tags: php, json

Desde un archivo .php envié la variable "myObj" a otro archivo diferente llamado test.php de la siguiente manera:

```
var myObj = { test: "test_x" };
var myJSON = JSON.stringify(myObj);
window.location="test.php?x=" + myJSON;
```

Luego voy a test.php y no se bien como descargar su contenido. He probado así:

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], true);
$valor_x = $obj->test;
echo $valor;
```

Pero no se me imprime nada por pantalla. Se ve que con `$_GET["x"]` no lo estoy haciendo bien. ¿Alguien me puede echar un cable?

Gracias de antemano por la ayuda!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden

Comment: Prueba a añadir `print_r($_GET);` y dinos que te muestra. Como extra decir que estas haciendo un echo a `$valor` mientras que la variable que recoge el objeto es `$valor_x`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo estas decodificando como array asociativo, para usarlo:

```
$valor_x = $obj['test'];
```

Y utiliza la misma variable para recoger el valor que para imprimir:

```
echo $valor_x;
```

Si lo quieres usar como objeto:

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
```

**Edición:**
Asociativo

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], true);
$valor_x = $obj['test'];
echo $valor_x;
```

Objeto

```
$obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], false);
$valor_x = $obj->test;
echo $valor_x;
```

Comment: lo de la misma variable era un error al escribirlo aquí. Eso está claro. Ahora lo he cambiado a false para que sea un objeto, pero nada... sigue sin funcionar...

Comment: Ya está claro. No había actualizado el 1er php. De todas formas gracias por lo del objeto.

Comment: Edité la respuesta para poner como quedaría el código de ambas formas. Ya veo que ya lo tienes ;-)

Comment: De nuevo muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de utilizar  `Echo`  para imprimir  prueba con `print_r();`

```html
if(isset($_GET['x')){
  $obj = json_decode($_GET["x"], true);
  $valor_x = $obj->test;
  echo "datos json to array <br>";
  print_r($valor);
}else{
  echo "no existe la variable x en GET";
}
```

Comment: Ese no es el problema, si el código está bien cuando imprime `$valor` debería tener un string. El problema casi seguro es que la variable que imprime y en la que almacena el objeto se llaman distinto